# POO listar registros

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Eai galera, qual desses jeitos é melhor para listar os registros do banco? O primeiro é o jeito estruturado e o segundo é o orientado a objetos não é? Valeu.

Primeiro:

```
$sql = $usuario -> listar();

foreach($sql AS $registro)
{
    echo $registro['nome'];
}
```

Segundo:

```
$sql = $usuario -> listar();

foreach($sql AS $registro)
{
    $usuario -> setNome($registro['nome']);
    echo $usuario -> getNome();
}
```

Comment: Sem contexto não tem melhor. E em PHP, as funções e métodos que possuem as 2 sintaxes são equivalentes (e podem ser misturadas no mesmo trecho de código, inclusive). Aliás, em PHP a orientação a objetos é irrelevante, e não acrescenta funcionalidades significativas. Tudo pode ser feito em qualquer dos 2 paradigmas.

Comment: **1)** Não entendi o segundo exemplo, você usa `setNome` e depois `getNome`, não vejo sentido nisso - a não ser que tenha outro contexto. **2)** Acho que sua dúvida é mais relacionada com *DAO* que *POO*.